# What is the language used on food can?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In season 2 episode 4, Reiner suspects Ymir.
While searching her, he found Ymir holding a can of canned food. When he took the food can, he was unable to read the content written on it, while Ymir could.
What is that language? and why was Reiner looking so afraid ?

[image: Attack on Titan S02E04]

Comment: Seems like it might be unknown, but I haven't been following SnK past the first season or so so can't verify: http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Unknown_writing

Comment: This is one of those things, that's in the manga, but it isn't in the anime, so if you don't want the story to get spoiled, you shouldn't read the answers

Comment: As of now, the language is unknown, with no reference even in the manga. However, there is a speculation that the language (very similar to the Wall Writings language) is an extinct language. It might be from one of the races that died out, or from outside the walls...

Comment: Titan's Language :v

Comment: If you're following the anime and not manga (which is pretty obvious by attached image) it would be wise to not to explore that answer right now. Since it can be a huge spoiler. Also, the language hadn't been mentioned before, so it's ok to not to know. They will eventually reveal it later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great question. However, as others mentioned, you do **not** want to know the answer by spoiling the anime.

You will know after the new episode which will be released today (S02E06), thus please read this spoiler only after you have watched the newest episode.

The actual name of the language is not known yet, but we know where it comes from. I will leave you with a small teaser.

> Reiner was pretending not to know the language.

Comment: Yeah.. got some idea after reading [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/40162/14063)

Comment: I highly recommend reading the manga other than reading spoilers here. It is all worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

> As Riener suffers from a personality disorder(Half of him thinking hes and elidan solider and the other half of him thinking as a Marley warrior). He infact is a Marley Warrior and can read the language on the canned food but his other half is unaware of his true persona and does not allow him to recognize this language.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references to support your claim. As far as I know, Reiner does not have a personality disorder. It was never shown in the manga nor did he show signs he has one.